# plsregress - can anyone explain the normalisation of features?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cross-validation

I am using plsregress in matlab as a feature reduction method before performing LDA. I am trying to cross validate my method, however have some trouble replicating their "data processing" stage.

> plsregress uses the SIMPLS algorithm, first centering X and Y by subtracting off column means to get centered variables X0 and Y0. However, it does not rescale the columns. To perform PLS with standardized variables, use zscore to normalize X and Y.

in order to try and replicate this on my "test" set I have done the following:

```
test = test - repmat(mean(test), DIM(1), 1);

test = Xloadings\test';
test = test';
```

This for some reason does not quite work, and when applied to the training set, I do not achieve the same Xscores.

Is anyone able to explain if there is a step I am missing, or something I am doing wrong?

EDIT: In other words, how to I apply the model generated by PLS to another dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the mean from the training set, not the test set.
This would also apply to normalization of sigma.

Use [Z,mu,sigma] = zscore(train).  Apply mu and sigma to test.